# Handling exceptions in MVC with Postsharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, postsharp

Handling exceptions with MVC + Postsharp.
This is my project architecture

MVC Project ->>> Business Layer ->>> DataLayer

> MVC Project (Added custom filter in Global file and created a Base Controller to catch exceptions.)
>
> Business Layer (middleware)
>
> DataLayer (connects to Postgres database server and fetches data.)

In the DataLayer I have added PostSharp to handle exceptions from the database side and logged/email using NLog.
Now from here I want to tell MVC Exception pipeline to display proper message to User that some exception has occured. So I use

```
args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.ThrowException;
```

Now I catching this exception at MVC OnException method.

ISSUE : I am also logging and sending email on exception at MVC Exception method as well for any exceptions occuring at MVC side.

Now the problem is I have already logged and sent email for the exeption which was handled by Postsharp and now when it reaches at MVC Exception handler will do that again.

How can I know at MVC that the exception has already been logged.
Can I do anything at Postsharp end like send some arguments in that which I can check at MVC Exception handler.

Please suggest a solution or guide to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

why are you trying to handle the exceptions in 2 places. Just pick either postsharp or the global MVC onException.

Alternatively, you could wrap the exception in a new exception. For example in postsharp you could say something like this

```
MyAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect {

    public override OnException (MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        ///your code to handle the exception here
        throw new HandledExceptin(args.Exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason for this is Postsharp gives us a better result in terms of what is the Method name being called and what were the arguments passed in. Now since exception has occuered at DataAccess layer and handled by Postsharp I wanted some mechanism to intimate User about some exception has occured.

Comment: Is there any reason why the wrapping exception does not solve your use case?